# Value for two days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that shows the interest rate on an account on a given day. I'm looking to query the interest rate on one day and the interest rate for the next day. Specifically, I'm looking to find accounts where the interest rate changed from one day to the next.

My data looks like this

**Account Number / Loan Number / Date / Interest Rate**
1234 / 5656 / 1/1/18 / 12%
1234 / 5656 / 1/2/18 / 12%
1234 / 5656 / 1/3/18 / 0%
1234 / 5656 / 1/4/18 / 0%

I want the query to return just the two days where the interest rate changed from 12% to 0%.

With the above data, it would return the following:

**Account Number / Loan Number / Date / Interest Rate / Next Day / Next Day Rate**
1234 / 5656 / 1/2/18 / 12% / 1/3/18 / 0%

The code I'm using (see below) is returning the same Date multiple times and modifying the "Next Day Rate" by some factor I cannot identify.

This is what I have so far.

```
select
tc.loanaccountid AS 'Account'
, l.LoanNumber AS 'Loan Number'
, tc.trialbalancedate AS 'Date'
, tc.interestrate AS 'Interest Rate'
, tb.trialbalancedate AS 'Next Day'
, tb.interestrate AS 'Next Day Rate'


from dbo.dailytrialbalance tc
join dbo.loanaccount l on tc.loanaccountid = l.loanaccountid
left join dbo.dailytrialbalance tb on dateadd(day, 1, tc.trialbalancedate) = 
tb.trialbalancedate


where tc.PortfolioCodeId = '10' 
and tc.interestrate = '0' 
and tb.interestrate > '0'
```

I'm still learning SQL, so any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what version of sql?

Comment: SQL Server 2014

Comment: is the value really 0% and 12% or 0.0 and 0.12

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way with `LEAD` for SQL Server 2012 onward. I added the `(SELECT NULL)` as a place holder for something more realistic to determine the difference since you have duplicate data for `1/2/18`:

```
with cte as(
select
tc.loanaccountid AS 'Account'
, l.LoanNumber AS 'Loan Number'
, tc.trialbalancedate AS 'Date'
, tc.interestrate AS 'Interest Rate'
, NextDay = lead(tc.trialbalancedate) over (partition by tc.loanaccountid order by tc.trialbalancedate, (select null)) 
, NextDayRate = lead(tc.interestrate) over (partition by tc.loanaccountid order by tc.trialbalancedate, (select null)) 
from dbo.dailytrialbalance tc
join dbo.loanaccount l on tc.loanaccountid = l.loanaccountid)

select * 
from cte 
where NextDayRate = 0 and [Interest Rate] != 0
```

[**Here is it in action**](http://rextester.com/XOTK38927), with your test data:

```
declare @testData table (AccountNumber int, LoanNumber int, Date date, InterestRate varchar(3))
insert into @testData
values

(1234,5656,'20180101','12%'),
(1234,5656,'20180102','12%'),
(1234,5656,'20180103','0%'),
(1234,5656,'20180104','0%')



;with cte as(
select
    AccountNumber
    ,LoanNumber
    ,[Date]
    ,InterestRate
    ,NextDay = lead([Date]) over (partition by AccountNumber order by [Date]) 
    ,NextDayRate = lead(InterestRate) over (partition by AccountNumber order by [Date]) 
from @testData)

select * 
from cte 
where NextDayRate = '0%' and InterestRate != '0%'
```

Comment: Thanks scsimon. I've updated the post to remove the duplicates. I tried your query and it returned multiples records for each account and all showed no change between the days. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Texas2014 I can't tell you why that is happening with the small data set you provided. As you can see by my edit, it works perfectly with your sample data.